# How to asynchronously memoize a field of struct in an Option

Tags: asynchronous, rust, option-type, borrow-checker

Suppose I have some data `Bar` (e.g. database client) which I would like to create only once
but lazily for my structure `Foo`.

```rust
struct Bar;

struct Foo {
    bar: Option<Bar>
}
```

To do this, I check that the field is initialized; if not, I run the async routine.
The result of the routine is then saved as `Some` to reuse later.

I know, that [Option::get_or_insert_with](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.get_or_insert_with) perfectly fits this scenario, but I have to
deal with async, so I do this manually like this.

```rust
impl Foo {
    pub async fn get_bar(&mut self) -> &Bar {
        if let Some(bar) = &self.bar {
            return bar;
        }
        
        let bar = Self::create_bar().await;
        self.bar.insert(bar)
    }
    
    /// Long and heavy-resource routine,
    /// we want to memoize it.
    async fn create_bar() -> Bar {
        Bar
    }
}
```

However, this cannot be compiled due to the immutable **and** mutable borrowing of `self.bar`.
Is there a way to do this correctly?

[Full example](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=c3af42896f296fcc1db55807da09435d).

Comment: I believe this is caused by a limitation of the borrow checker: https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/issues/54663

Comment: You can work around it by checking `is_some()` beforehand: https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=a10ee8d50b9b1f22742c3b9a07b75236

Comment: This is the classic Polonius problem, it's interesting it is solved by `ref`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Interestingly the borrow checker is able to infer better lifetimes by using the `ref` keyword in your `if let` so the following [works](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=5cf947902c400c41ee7ecaadf5bcc985):

```rust
    pub async fn get_bar(&mut self) -> &Bar {
        if let Some(ref bar) = self.bar {
            return bar;
        }
        let bar = Self::create_bar().await;
        self.bar.insert(bar)
    }
```

Comment: Thanks! This works in my real code too! This seems strange to me, but the non-async version of `get_bar` faces the exact same problem with the borrow checker. So the problem is not specific to async. The `ref` really narrows down the lifetime of the reference to the `if` block, while in the original code, the BC evidently extends the lifetime of the reference to the whole function body. It is strange because I always thought the latter version (`if let Some(x) = &y`) is just the syntactic sugar for the former (the `ref` one).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [`as_ref()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/std/option/enum.Option.html#method.as_ref) method of `Option<T>`.

Here's it being used in your `get_bar()` function:

```
async fn get_bar(&mut self) -> &Bar {
    if self.bar.is_some() {
        self.bar.as_ref().unwrap()
    } else {
        let bar = Self::create_bar().await;
        self.bar.insert(bar)
    }
}
```

I posted this as an answer because my reputation is too low. Please let me know if this answer is not suitable.

Comment: nit: you don't need the `&` on line 3

Comment: Also, you may want to clarify that what allows this to work is checking `is_some` manually, not just use `as_ref`